# How to configure Sonar analysis for an ANT project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ant, sonarqube

I have my ANT based Java project in Git and I want to perform static code analysis for my project using SonarQube and Jenkins.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the `sonar` analysis for your ant project in two ways.

1. By adding a new Sonar target to your `build.xml`

   Follow this document for the steps: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant
2. Using `Sonar Scanner`

   Follow this document for the steps:
   https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

Comment: Hello, Anil MahaPatra, I have done above changes. Please let me know how to configure it in Jenkins. Thank you for your  prompt response.

Comment: which configuration have you followed?

Comment: first cofiguration

Comment: Okay, if you have used the first configuration then, in your Jenkins job in `Build` section choose `Execute windows batch script` if you are executing it in a `Windows` machine or choose `Execute shell` if you are executing it in a `Linux` machine and add this command there:
`cd \path\to\build.xml
ant sonar`

Then build your job.

Comment: You can login to your `SonarQube` dashboard by using its URL. You can find the analysis in its dashboard.

Comment: sorry. Earlier comment was wrong. In Execute shell if i add  "cd \path\to\build.xml ant sonar" build fails and gives me error like  Not a directory.

Comment: By `cd \path\to\build.xml` I meant changing your directory to the folder where you have your `build.xml` file. Then in the next line run `ant sonar`.

`cd <PATH_TO_BUILDXML>` in the next line

`ant sonar`

Comment: i'm giving correct path for build.xml, still it is giving me same error. i.e. Not a directory.

Comment: can you post your command here?

Comment: it is difficult for me, but it is something like this. cd /somefolder/somefolder build.xml ant sonar

Comment: just `cd /somefolder/somefolder` do not mention `build.xml`. `cd` - change directory, you cannot mention a file name.

Comment: Thanks ANIL. It solved my problem. Sorry for late response.

Comment: If it did then please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: how to make it?